# Label as title in TextArea HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-framework-7

[image]

I'm building a hybrid mobile app UI using Framework7, and this is the screenshot of what I'm going to implement.

The text will be entered in `textarea` entity. But I'm not sure how to implement the title "DESCRIPTION" to make it work as follows.

Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
textarea {
  position:absolute;
     
     text-indent: 80px;
 }
 label { 
   position:relative;   
     
 }
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Textarea placeholder"></textarea>
<label for="qual">Description:</label>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please have a look on the image carefully, the 2nd line should start below of the title at same horizontal position. And the first line starts right after the title.